# Can't make a proper if statement for something with a property of null in a for loop

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Coding a warn command for my discord.js bot, and I added a feature so that the `lw` command returns the list of warns from a specified user.

The code works well, but if I ping a user that doesn't have any warns, the bot gets an error saying `cannot read property of null`

I am using mongoDB as my database.

Here is the code for the command itself, (using an advanced command handler that is working fine in another file):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const mongo = require('../../mongo')
const warnSchema = require('../../schemas/warn-schema')

module.exports = {
    commands: ['listwarnings', 'listwarns', 'listwarn', 'lw'],
    minArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: "<Target user's @>",
    callback: async (message, arguments, text) => {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (!target) {
            const noPingListWarns = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription('Please specify a valid user to tag.')
            message.channel.send(noPingListWarns)
            return
        }

        const guildId = message.guild.id
        const userId = message.member.id

        await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
            try {
                const results = await warnSchema.findOne({
                    guildId,
                    userId
                })

                let reply = `Previous warnings for <@${target}>:\n\n`

                for (const warning of results.warnings) {

                    const { author, timestamp, reason } = warning

                    reply += `By ${author} on ${new Date(timestamp).toLocaleDateString()} for "${reason}"\n\n`
                }

                const listWarningsReply = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(reply)
                message.channel.send(listWarningsReply)
            } finally {
                mongoose.connection.close()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I want the bot to reply saying `message.channel.send(`<@${target}> has 0 warns.` in an if statement where the condition is that if warns = 0. I tried to make an if statement outside the for loop, and inside it and it still doesn't work...

If it is of any help, here is the code from the schema I used for mongoDB:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const warnSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    guildId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    warnings: {
        type: [Object],
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('warnings', warnSchema)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over here

```js
const results = await warnSchema.findOne({
                    guildId,
                    userId
                })

                let reply = `Previous warnings for <@${target}>:\n\n`

                for (const warning of results.warnings) {

                    const { author, timestamp, reason } = warning

                    reply += `By ${author} on ${new Date(timestamp).toLocaleDateString()} for "${reason}"\n\n`
                }
```

You can check if it is null (I don’t know what is null exactly you did not provide enough info)

```js
const results = await warnSchema.findOne({
                    guildId,
                    userId
                })
                if(!results?.warnings?.length) return message.channel.send(`<@${target}> has 0 warns.`);
//I assume results.warnings.length is 0 if there are none
                let reply = `Previous warnings for <@${target}>:\n\n`

                for (const warning of results.warnings) {

                    const { author, timestamp, reason } = warning

                    reply += `By ${author} on ${new Date(timestamp).toLocaleDateString()} for "${reason}"\n\n`
                }
```